# ESP32 JTAG Programming fails at Verification

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, platformio, jtag

The code is working. I can build it and to mention. it was working, i could upload it to my custom made ESP32 board. From all of a sudden it stopped working. Tried with different PCB boards also different cables.
I somehow resolved my problem so i can program it, but now i get a verification error after **Programming Finished**

Here is my complete log from terminal.

```
Processing esp32dev (platform: espressif32; board: esp32dev; framework: espidf)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif32/esp32dev.html
PLATFORM: Espressif 32 (3.4.0) > Espressif ESP32 Dev Module
HARDWARE: ESP32 240MHz, 320KB RAM, 4MB Flash
DEBUG: Current (esp-prog) External (esp-prog, iot-bus-jtag, jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h, olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa)
PACKAGES: 
 - framework-espidf 3.40301.0 (4.3.1) 
 - tool-cmake 3.16.4 
 - tool-esptoolpy 1.30100.210531 (3.1.0) 
 - tool-mkspiffs 2.230.0 (2.30) 
 - tool-ninja 1.9.0 
 - tool-openocd-esp32 2.1000.20210721 (10.0) 
 - toolchain-esp32ulp 1.22851.191205 (2.28.51) 
 - toolchain-riscv32-esp 8.4.0+2021r1 
 - toolchain-xtensa-esp32 8.4.0+2021r1 
 - toolchain-xtensa-esp32s2 8.4.0+2021r1
Reading CMake configuration...
LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> 
LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
Found 0 compatible libraries
Scanning dependencies...
No dependencies
Building in debug mode
Retrieving maximum program size .pio/build/esp32dev/firmware.elf
Checking size .pio/build/esp32dev/firmware.elf
Advanced Memory Usage is available via "PlatformIO Home > Project Inspect"
RAM:   [=         ]  10.1% (used 32992 bytes from 327680 bytes)
Flash: [========  ]  75.7% (used 794197 bytes from 1048576 bytes)
Configuring upload protocol...
AVAILABLE: esp-prog, espota, esptool, iot-bus-jtag, jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h, olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa
CURRENT: upload_protocol = esp-prog
Uploading .pio/build/esp32dev/firmware.bin
Open On-Chip Debugger  v0.10.0-esp32-20210721 (2021-07-21-13:34)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
debug_level: 1

adapter speed: 20000 kHz

WARNING: boards/esp-wroom-32.cfg is deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
adapter speed: 2000 kHz

** Programming Started **
** Programming Finished **
** Verify Started **
Error: **** Verification failure! ****
Error: target_hash cbc6a9...992065
Error: file_hash: 773d62...93803f
embedded:startup.tcl:449: Error: ** Verify Failed **
in procedure 'program_esp' 
in procedure 'program_error' called at file "/Users/USER/.platformio/packages/tool-openocd-esp32/share/openocd/scripts/target/esp_common.cfg", line 135
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 449
*** [upload] Error 1
```

Comment: What debug adapter hardware (ESP-Prog?) and which interface (UART or JTAG) are you using? The standard advice is to use a short cable and reduce the interface's speed - there is no need to run it at 2Mbaud as writing to Flash is an order of magnitude slower than that.

Comment: Yes i'm using the esp-prog and via JTAG. i tried with different adapter speeds. also with 500khz i get the same verify error. Also here is my platformio.ini file.[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
;platform = https://github.com/platformio/platform-espressif32.git
;platform = https://github.com/platformio/platform-espressif32#feature/openocd-update

board = esp32dev
framework = espidf

debug_tool = esp-prog
debug_init_break = tbreak app_main


upload_port = /dev/ttyUSB1
upload_protocol = esp-prog
build_type = debug
;build_type = release
debug_speed = 500

Comment: You haven't enabled Flash encryption or Secure Boot by chance?

Comment: I tried with 500khz adapter speed and i made a really short (5-7cm) cable. Now it works. Thank you for the advice!!

Comment: Debugging still does not work, I can only upload the code.